# Matlab Compiler Runtime: Cannot find javabuilder.jar

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, matlab, maven

I have been trying to set up a web service in Java using Maven. The web server is Wildfly 9.0.0 (JBoss) and previously Wildfly 8.2.0. The goal of this web service is for the client to send a list of values, and then the server gathers these values into a csv file and feed that file to a MATLAB application, which is compiled into a java jar, that resides in the server's side. Both client and server are developed in eclipse, but the execution is done through command prompt/terminal

What has already been set up:

1.MCR 8.1 for linux (64bit) is properly installed. (Version chosen to be compliant with the MATLAB version used to build the application)

2.LD_LIBRARY_PATH and XAPPLRESDIR has been set up accordingly (via export commands) in the ~/.bashrc file (any other way to set them either does not work (/etc/profile.d/*.sh file), or does not let linux to log in after restarting the PC (/etc/environment)).

2a. The same is true for the M2_HOME variable

3.The Javabuilder jar (copied from the MCR folders) and the jar containing the MATLAB application have been added to the maven repository and properly mentioned in the .pom file of the server.

Upon trying to execute the client side, the server says that an exception is being thrown which has quite a long stack (I can provide it if you want) and refers to the internal procedures of JBoss. But I guess the real problem and therefore, the one that puzzles me the most are the underlying causes:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.internal.MCRConfiguration.getProxyLibraryDir(MCRConfiguration.java:173)
at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.internal.MCRConfiguration$MCRRoot.get(MCRConfiguration.java:74)
at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.internal.MCRConfiguration$MCRRoot.<clinit>(MCRConfiguration.java:84)
at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.internal.MCRConfiguration.getMCRRoot(MCRConfiguration.java:89)
at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.internal.MCRConfiguration$ModuleDir.<clinit>(MCRConfiguration.java:63)
at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.internal.MCRConfiguration.getModuleDir(MCRConfiguration.java:68)
at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.internal.MWMCR.<clinit>(MWMCR.java:1466)
... 39 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.internal.MCRConfiguration$ProxyLibraryDir.get(MCRConfiguration.java:138)
at com.mathworks.toolbox.javabuilder.internal.MCRConfiguration$ProxyLibraryDir.<clinit>(MCRConfiguration.java:168)
... 88 more
```

Which means (if I understand it correctly) that the javabuilder.jar is not being read from any place that it exists. Even going into eclipse, adding directly the path of the MCR's javabuilder jar to the project build path, and building it again with the proper maven commands in the terminal was still no good.

What am I missing here? In windows, this arrangement works perfectly and the MATLAB application is executed as usual, but unfortunately we need to run this whole thing in linux.

DISCLAIMER: I am aware of the other similar issues raised here in the past. So before posting I read all them very carefully and did all of these things described there (install MCR, check variables, etc). But since the problem persists, I had no choice but to ask the community for help.

Comment: Does the webserver run MCR as the same user for which you have setup the bashrc file?

Comment: How can I check that? As far as I have understood (but I could be wrong), all that is required from the MCR are some ".so" libraries during the execution. Since LD_LIBRARY_PATH is configured properly, these libraries are read, and the execution is carried out until the error I described originally, emerges.
Furthermore, if it is of any help, I use the administrator account to do all the work, and I use administrator rights to start the server and edit the bashrc file:
sudo ./standalone.sh
sudo gedit ~/.bashrc

Comment: I do not know about wildfly. This is normally a setting in the config file. For example for apache, there is a setting called "User". Apache usually defaults to something like www-data.

Comment: Well, it might have been the case... I tried running sudo -s in both terminals before opening the server and running my app, and it works. Now I am dealing with java.awt.headlessexception, buth that's another story.
Thanks anyway.